# Errors Creating App Package (UWP, Appx) - fatal error CMF1106: failed to open input PDB file for reading

Tags: msbuild, azure-pipelines, nodatime

I'm getting errors when Creating App Packages for a UWP Win 10 application.

On my machine the error is:

`C:\Users\Developer\.nuget\packages\nodatime\2.4.0\lib\netstandard2.0\NodaTime.pdb : fatal error CMF1106: failed to open input PDB file for reading (PDB error code = 11)3 input PDB file is not generated by /DEBUG:fastlinkW must read and agree to the Data Collection Policy at MSPDBCMF : fatal error CMF1000: internal error`

The pdb file exists in the mentioned directory: `C:\Users\Developer\.nuget\packages\nodatime\2.4.0\lib\netstandard2.0`

---

On a hosted VSTS build the error message is even more cryptic:

`C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.nuget\packages\nodatime\2.4.0\lib\netstandard2.0\NodaTime.pdb : fatal error CMF1106: failed to open input PDB file for reading (PDB error code = 11)3 input PDB file is not generated by /DEBUG:fastlinkW must read and agree to the Data Collection Policy at ??? before using /errorreport:send1 warning treated as error; the PDB file is intact@ specified output filename is too long (exceeding 0 characters)`

---

*Note 1*: On my machine the package is actaully successfully created but on the VSTS build the step fails as it detects the error in logs and stops.

*Note 2*: I'm pretty sure this is **not** NodaTime specific. This is about something else...

My `msbuild` switches are:

- /p:AppxBundlePlatforms="$(BuildPlatform)"
- /p:AppxPackageDir="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\AppxPackages\"
- /p:AppxBundle=Never
- /p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=StoreUpload

I am now trying with extra `/p:DebugSymbols=false /p:DebugType=None`, but even if it fails, I would like to understand and eliminate the 'fastlink' errors.

Comment: Possibly it's an issue using portable PDBs? Do you see the same issue with Noda Time 2.3.0 which didn't include the netstandard2.0 target?

Comment: I'm having the same issue running a UWP build today, however the build succeed even in case of this error. I'm my situation it fails on ColorCode.Core.pdb, so it looks to be independent to NodaTime. The same build ran successfully 7 days ago and the only thing I did was change a few lines of code. I didn't make any changes to the project configuration or NuGet packages.

Comment: Hi. Mirko from UWP here. We're aware of this issue and I'm working on a fix. Seems to be an issue with our version of mspdbcmf and netstandard pdbs, at this point.
Please keep an eye on this Developer Community ticket for updates: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/307296/error-msb6006-mspdbcmfexe-exited-with-code-1106.html

Comment: @tymtam Did you figure out a workaround?  Hoping to unblock our build machines before Visual Studio 15.9 Preview 3.

Comment: @Felix Embarrassingly, I don't remember the fix/workaround and . MsBuild is now run with `/p:AppxBundlePlatforms="$(BuildPlatform)" /p:AppxPackageDir="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\AppxPackages\\" /p:AppxBundle=Never /p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=StoreUpload`

Also our top level UWP projects are very thin and we run them with TreatWarningsAsErrors=false because of a .net native compiler issue.

Comment: @tymtam Ah, no worries.  Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly setting `DebugType` to `pdbonly` worked in my case, but not sure if you need portable debug symbols or not, so this might not be an option for you.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
</PropertyGroup>
```