# Commit and building CI

Tags: c#, tfs, continuous-integration

Hello when I commit a change , TFS automatically builds. The build has status succeeded. But with 2 the same error messages :

```
Cannot find path '/C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual
Studio/2017/Enterprise/MSBuild/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v15.0/AppxPackage/Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets'
at 'Commit 603cb0a3', or you do not have permission
```

I don't have have the folder 'Enterprise' becouse I work with Community version.
How can I 'resolve' this 2 error's?

2018-09-30T17:08:07.8348986Z   C:\Users\VssAdministrator.nuget\packages\mvvmlightlibsstd10\5.4.1.1\lib\uap10.0\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.pdb : fatal error CMF1106: failed to open input PDB file for reading (PDB error code = 11)3 input PDB file is not generated by /DEBUG:fastlinkW must read and agree to the Data Collection Policy at ft MPI\Bin\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\ProgramData\Chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Docker;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\Fabric\Fabric.Code;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\Tools\ServiceFabricLocalClusterManager;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Subversion\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps before using /errorreport:send1 warning treated as error; the PDB file is intact@ specified output filename is too long (exceeding 0 characters)

2018-09-30T17:08:07.9262029Z ##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(3357,5): Error MSB6006: "mspdbcmf.exe" exited with code 1106.
2018-09-30T17:08:07.9292462Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(3357,5): error MSB6006: "mspdbcmf.exe" exited with code 1106. [D:\a\1\s\MyProject\MyProject.csproj]

Comment: Can you share the detailed error logs?

Comment: @EddieChen-MSFT, Thats all error log I get. Where can I get the more detailed error log?

Comment: What's your TFS version? Do you use XAML build or vNext build?

Comment: @EddieChen-MSFT, will check when I got home. I just use TFS online, now its called DevOps azure.

Comment: Then you should see a link to download the logs

Comment: @EddieChen-MSFT, indeed have them downloaded. But the build has the status Succeeded. But with Errors, are this administrative errors?

Answer (score 1):

Seems there is an issue here : [error MSB6006: "mspdbcmf.exe" exited with code 1106](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/307296/error-msb6006-mspdbcmfexe-exited-with-code-1106.html)

Based on **Mirko Muggli's** comment, this issue is fixed and it will be available in VS 15.9 Preview 3.

You can also reference this similar thread : [Errors Creating App Package (UWP, Appx) - fatal error CMF1106: failed to open input PDB file for reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52031702/errors-creating-app-package-uwp-appx-fatal-error-cmf1106-failed-to-open-in)